# Javascript closures - lifetime of variables

Tags: javascript, closures

Being fairly new to Javascript and from a c# background I have been stumbling along adequately. I knew that soon enough I would need to get my head round the fact that functions are objects in their own right and that JS closures are often the cause of confusion.

I am trying to understand this little snippet of code

```
// Function which returns object with function properties
function myFunc() {

    value = 42;

    var result = {
        value: value,
        getValue: getValue,
        incrementValue: incrementValue,
        setValue: setValue,
    };
    return result; 

    function setValue(y) {
        value = y;
    };

    function getValue() {
         return value;   
    }; 

    function incrementValue() {
        value++;
    };
};

// Helper function to print out results
function printResults(m,x){
    $('#output').append(m + ': ' + x).append('<br/>');
};

var myObject = myFunc();  // returns the object 
printResults('Inital call to getValue',myObject.getValue());

myObject.setValue(59);
printResults('Called changeValue',myObject.getValue());

printResults('Value property of object',myObject.value);
printResults('Called getValue again',myObject.getValue());

myObject.incrementValue();
printResults('Call increment value',myObject.getValue());
printResults('Value property of object',myObject.value);
```

I get the following results when run in jsFiddle

```
Inital call to getValue: 42
Called changeValue: 59
Value property of object: 42
Called getValue again: 59
Call increment value: 60
Value property of object: 42
```

These show that the functions are using the variable `value` within their closure and this persists between invocation of the inner functions. BUT, the value of `value` does not change in the returned object.

I think I get the basic point that functions are executed using the scope chain that was in effect when they were defined.

**Questions**
Can I make the `value` property of the returned object operate in the same way - or is the only way to return it via a function, since the latter retains the variable in its closure?

**And**, just for confirmation, for every invocation of `myFunc()`, I assume I will get an object whose function properties will have their own scope chain and therefore independent of each invocation.

Comment: Tip: no semicolons after blocks, e.g. in function declarations.

Comment: @minitech Doesn't really matter, and isn't even completely true. `var func = function(){};` doesn't require a semi-colon, because JavaScript in general does not require a semi-colon, but linters will still mark it. But that is the only case where your statement isn't quite true... and somewhat special. :P

Comment: @Derija93: In your exception case, the block still doesn’t end with a semicolon, but the variable declaration does.

Comment: @minitech And that's pretty much the *special* I'm referring to.

Comment: @Derija93: It’s not a special case. Terminate all statements with semicolons. A block isn’t a statement.

Comment: @minitech That's generally correct syntax, but only required in *strict mode*.

Comment: @Derija93: Er, no. Strict mode doesn’t affect ASI, to my eternal dismay.

Comment: @minitech Well, that's even worse, meaning that it is basically only recommended... regardless, this is becoming quite long.

Comment: @Derija93: I’m not really talking about omitting semicolons, I’m talking about having too many, which is pretty objectively wrong. cf. `myObject.incrementValue();;;;;;;;; printResults();;;`

Comment: @minitech Yes, but omitting semicolons and having too many doesn't really matter to the interpreter. They're redundant and pretty much no-ops. The code just maybe becomes harder to read and surely unnecessarily bigger in size. That's the only thing I'm talking about.

Comment: Just exemplifying, when writing a one-liner `function a(){}function b(){}`, you do not need semicolons since you are dealing with blocks, but variable declarations require them. e.g. `a=function(){}b=function{}` would cause a syntax error.

Comment: This behaves exactly the same in C#, by the way, if that helps you think about the semantics of assignment and whatnot.

Comment: @GuilhermeSehn I wasn't talking about one-liners. Obviously for those you definitely need to put semicolons (or commas in your example). I was thinking about writing each statement in a new line.

Comment: @Derija93 I agree that when you are putting each statement in a new line, semicolons are optional and are not required at all. However, what I think he is trying to say is that if you want to put semicolons anyway, use them just in the places they would be required if the language didn't have ASI. And functions declared as blocks would not require.

Comment: @GuilhermeSehn Well that... could have cut this little disputation down to a minimum.

Comment: ["The moral of this story: ASI is (formally speaking) a syntactic error correction procedure."](https://brendaneich.com/2012/04/the-infernal-semicolon/)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

First of all, do not forget the `var` keyword when declaring variables. When you declare `value = 42` inside `myFunc`, you are actually creating a variable in the global namespace instead of the function scope. It should start like this:

```
function myFunc() {
    var value = 42;
```

Now, `myObject.result` is returning 42 because `myFunc` returns your `result` object which contains a copy of the `value` variable declared inside the function.

Your functions `setValue`, `getValue` and `incrementValue` are changing the value of `value`, not `result.value`. When you call `myObject.value`, you are getting the value from the returned object, not the inner variable of your function.

You could get it to work using something like this:

```
function myFunc() {
    var value = 42;
    var result = {
        value: value,
        getValue: getValue,
        incrementValue: incrementValue,
        setValue: setValue
    };

    return result;

    function setValue(y) {
        result.value = y;
    }

    function getValue() {
        return result.value;
    }

    function incrementValue() {
        result.value++;
    }
}
```

However, there are better design patterns than this. You could use the `new` keyword and `prototype` to define the methods available for the objects returned from your function. Take this example:

```
function myFunc() {
    this.value = 42;
}

myFunc.prototype.setValue = function(y) {
    this.value = y;
}

myFunc.prototype.getValue = function(y) {
    return this.value;
}

myFunc.prototype.incrementValue = function(y) {
    this.value++;
}

var myObject = new myFunc();
console.log(myObject.getValue()); // 42
myObject.setValue(30);
myObject.incrementValue();
console.log(myObject.getValue()); // 31
```

Comment: It would be nice if you explain that primitives are copied. That is why value is copied to the return object. On the other hand, objects are not copied. For them, assignments are just an alias for the same obect.

Comment: @Walter: This might actually be an implementation detail. Since primitive values are *immutable* you cannot tell (by executing the  code only) whether primitives are also not just references.

Comment: Note that both examples expose a different behavior than the OP's code. In both of them you can also change the value through `myObject.value = newValue;` (in addition to `myObject.setValue`). This wasn't possible in the original code.

Comment: Agreed. My comment intent is only to clarify why 'value' in return object is not the same declared inside the function.

Comment: Thanks for pointing it out. It will surely clarify any doubt that may arise from my comment.

Comment: @WalterMacambira: *Every value* in Javascript is copied when passed or assigned. "Objects" are not values in JavaScript. The only values you can manipulate in JavaScript are primitives and references (pointers to objects), just like in Java.

Comment: @newacct I am talking about the variable 'value'.

Comment: @WalterMacambira: The value of a variable is either a primitive or a pointer to an object. That's the only formal concept of value.

Comment: @newacct And I am not disagreeing of that, you just misread what I said.

Answer (score 1):

> Can I make the value property of the returned object operate in the same way

If you mean that it shows the updated value, yes, you can do that. You just have to change the code to update the `value` property as well:

```
function myFunc() {

    var value = 42; // don't forget var!

    var result = {
        value: value,
        getValue: getValue,
        incrementValue: incrementValue,
        setValue: setValue,
    };
    return result; 

    function setValue(y) {
        result.value = value = y;
    }

    function getValue() {
         return value;   
    }

    function incrementValue() {
        value++;
        result.value = value;
    }
}
```

The reason why I choose to use both `value` and `result.value` is to prevent the modification of the value through `result.value`. If you notice, I don't internally *read* from `result.value`, I only write to it. That means that assignments to `result.value` from *external* code doesn't have an effect. This conforms to how your existing code works.

> And, just for confirmation, for every invocation of `myFunc()`, I assume I will get an object whose function properties will have their own scope chain and therefore independent of each invocation.

Yes, every invocation of `myFunc` creates a new object and new functions and they are completely independent from objects/functions created by previous invocations.

Comment: So does that mean that by referencing the result variable it stays within the inner function's closure between invocations?

Comment: I'm not sure what you mean. The functions defined inside `myFunc` have access to all other variables that are defined within `myFunc`. So they have access to `value` and `result`.

Comment: Apologies for my naivety. I would expect that the `value` property of the returned object is a reference to the same variable which the inner functions are using. So when `changeValue` changes the `value` variable I would expect that to be reflected the `value` property of the returned object. What am I missing? Why do we have to set `result.value` rather than the variable `value` - do they not refer to the same place? Very much appreciate the help in understanding this.

Comment: @jcaddy: Whether they do or don’t refer to the same place initially is pretty much irrelevant – in JavaScript, it’s actually safe to assume that everything is a “reference”. What is important is that, by doing `.value = somethingNew`, you are overwriting that reference. If it was a reference, it no longer points to the same place. Even `.value++` is shorthand for `.value = .value + 1`; nothing is happening “in place”.

Comment: @minitech I'd put it in a shorter way: All objects are referenced while primitives are copied. When the OP declares and initiates the property `value`, it receives a copy of the variable `value` and from then on is independent from its "origin". Now I'm not sure whether strings are accounted for as objects or primitives...

Comment: @Derija93: It doesn’t matter whether you see primitives as “values” or “references”, or whether they’re copied or not. Since they’re immutable, there would be no difference in behaviour.

Comment: @minitech Makes sense, but it certainly helps understanding it.

Comment: Strings are primitives,  as null, undefined and numbers.

Comment: @jcaddy: No, it's not a reference. I don't know C#, but I assume if you have `int foo = 42;` and `int bar = foo;`, then assigning a new value to `bar` wouldn't assign the value to `foo`, or would it?

Comment: @Derija93: This is actually not correct. All values are copied. The value of an object is actually a reference to the object and it's the reference that is copied. I see it like this: Variables are independent value containers. Assigning a value to a variable never changes the value of another variable. But two variables can refer to the same value (e.g. an object) and that object can then be changed from either variable (and of course those changes are also visible through the other variable since they both refer to the same object).

Comment: I have gleaned quite a bit from all these comments - thanks to everyone for engaging. It seems that, `value` is a property of the returned object - it has been assigned a primitive (i.e. int) and therefor (just as in C#) the value would be copied during assignment. Of course the function properties are also copied - but since their value is a reference (as in C#) they are referencing the same code. At this point you all pipe up that I still haven't got it! Thanks to all - all comments very helpful - even the semicolon discussion!

Comment: Just for my own satisfaction, I changed the `value` property to be a simple object `var myInternalObject = { value: 42 };` - changed the code a bit, and indeed I got the behaviour expected as the property was no longer a primitive.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, you can:

```
var result = {
    get value() {
        return value;
    },
    getValue: getValue,
    incrementValue: incrementValue,
    setValue: setValue,
};
```

Hooray for ECMAScript 5. Of course, this won’t work on IE < 8.

<aside>`value = 42;` should be `var value = 42;`.</aside>

This doesn’t have a lot to do with the lifetime of variables, by the way – it’s just how assignment works. There are references in JavaScript, but no “reference variables” or “reference properties”. The object contains a copy of whatever `value` was at the time; creating a getter like this is just like creating a function that’s called implicitly.

Comment: I have just responded to Felix King above and I see that your post may answer this. So, in JS, variables are not references to objects - they ARE the objects?

Comment: @jcaddy: You can definitely think of all of them as references to objects, but you’re overwriting the references; I added a comment on Felix Kling’s answer with more detail. :)